# Parse XML file into Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, xml, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to parse the below xml into a Pandas dataframe that would like something like the below:

[image]

xml_data

```
`<Data>
<Request>
<Type>TIMESERIES_LIST</Type>
<Params>
<GroupId>152</GroupId>
<FromUTC>2020-06-17T11:00:00.000Z</FromUTC>
<UntilUTC>2020-06-17T13:00:00.000Z</UntilUTC>
</Params>
</Request>
<TimeseriesList>
<Timeseries>
<Header>
<TimeserieId>509</TimeserieId>
<ObjectID>EntryArnoldstein_GebuchteKapazitaetJaehrlich</ObjectID>
<Unit>kWh/h</Unit>
<Granularity>HOUR</Granularity>
<Name>BCY En Arnoldstein</Name>
<LastUpdate>2020-03-02T14:40:00.000Z</LastUpdate>
</Header>
<Values>
<Value FromUTC="2020-06-17T11:00:00.000Z" UntilUTC="2020-06-17T12:00:00.000Z">521331.0</Value>
<Value FromUTC="2020-06-17T12:00:00.000Z" UntilUTC="2020-06-17T13:00:00.000Z">521331.0</Value>
</Values>
</Timeseries>
<Timeseries>
<Header>
<TimeserieId>530</TimeserieId>
<ObjectID>EntryArnoldstein_TechnischeKapazitaetJaehrlich</ObjectID>
<Unit>kWh/h</Unit>
<Granularity>HOUR</Granularity>
<Name>TCY En Arnoldstein</Name>
<LastUpdate>2020-03-02T19:00:08.000Z</LastUpdate>
</Header>
<Values>
<Value FromUTC="2020-06-17T11:00:00.000Z" UntilUTC="2020-06-17T12:00:00.000Z">17377622</Value>
<Value FromUTC="2020-06-17T12:00:00.000Z" UntilUTC="2020-06-17T13:00:00.000Z">17377622</Value>
</Values>
</Timeseries>
</TimeseriesList>
</Data>`


`#xml data as string easier to paste
xml_data = '<Data><Request><Type>TIMESERIES_LIST</Type><Params> 
<GroupId>152</GroupId><FromUTC>2020-06-17T11:00:00.000Z</FromUTC> 
<UntilUTC>2020-06-17T13:00:00.000Z</UntilUTC></Params></Request> 
<TimeseriesList><Timeseries><Header><TimeserieId>509</TimeserieId> 
<ObjectID>EntryArnoldstein_GebuchteKapazitaetJaehrlich</ObjectID> 
<Unit>kWh/h</Unit><Granularity>HOUR</Granularity><Name>BCY En 
Arnoldstein</Name><LastUpdate>2020-03-02T14:40:00.000Z</LastUpdate></Header> 
<Values><Value FromUTC="2020-06-17T11:00:00.000Z" UntilUTC="2020-06- 
17T12:00:00.000Z">521331.0</Value><Value FromUTC="2020-06-17T12:00:00.000Z" 
UntilUTC="2020-06-17T13:00:00.000Z">521331.0</Value></Values></Timeseries> 
<Timeseries><Header><TimeserieId>530</TimeserieId> 
<ObjectID>EntryArnoldstein_TechnischeKapazitaetJaehrlich</ObjectID> 
<Unit>kWh/h</Unit><Granularity>HOUR</Granularity><Name>TCY En 
Arnoldstein</Name><LastUpdate>2020-03-02T19:00:08.000Z</LastUpdate></Header> 
<Values><Value FromUTC="2020-06-17T11:00:00.000Z" UntilUTC="2020-06- 
17T12:00:00.000Z">17377622</Value><Value FromUTC="2020-06-17T12:00:00.000Z" 
UntilUTC="2020-06-17T13:00:00.000Z">17377622</Value></Values></Timeseries> 
</TimeseriesList></Data>'`
```

The below code works for another xml I have but for the above it only returns:
[image]

I guess I need to start iterating from the Header level?

```
root = et.XML(xml_data) # element tree
all_records = []
for i, child in enumerate(root):
    record = {}
    for subchild in child:
        record[subchild.tag] = subchild.text
    all_records.append(record)
df = pd.DataFrame(all_records)
```

any thoughts much appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below uses python's [xml etree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) module, and filters through specific elements to get your output.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from itertools import product, chain

root = ET.parse('test.xml').getroot()

elements = ['TimeserieId', 'ObjectID', 'Unit', 'Granularity','Name','LastUpdate','Value']
box = []
for entry in root.findall(".//Timeseries"):
    #initialize dictionary within for loop
    #to create new dict everytime we hit another Timeseries element
    d = {}
    for key in elements:
        for ent in entry.findall(f".//{key}"):
            d[key] = ent.text
        #get values from the Values element
        content = [ent.attrib for ent in entry.findall(f".//Values/Value")]
    #combine the dictionary with the list of values[FromUTC, UntilUTC]
    #this will be a generator expression containing two dictionaries
    #this way, we pair the dictionary with each FromUTC and UntilUTC
    merger = product([d],content)
    #merge the dictionaries in each sub generator expression
    #I would suggest you run the code step by step to understand what is 
    #going on here
    #you could even spot some opportunity for optimization
    merger = [{**dict1, **dict2} for dict1, dict2 in merger]
    
    #at the end of every iteration within the for loop
    #append the result from merger to the box list
    #this will hold the results of the iteration 
    #from which our dataframe will be created
    box.append(merger)

print(box)

[[{'TimeserieId': '509',
   'ObjectID': 'EntryArnoldstein_GebuchteKapazitaetJaehrlich',
   'Unit': 'kWh/h',
   'Granularity': 'HOUR',
   'Name': 'BCY En Arnoldstein',
   'LastUpdate': '2020-03-02T14:40:00.000Z',
   'Value': '521331.0',
   'FromUTC': '2020-06-17T11:00:00.000Z',
   'UntilUTC': '2020-06-17T12:00:00.000Z'},
  {'TimeserieId': '509',
   'ObjectID': 'EntryArnoldstein_GebuchteKapazitaetJaehrlich',
   'Unit': 'kWh/h',
   'Granularity': 'HOUR',
   'Name': 'BCY En Arnoldstein',
   'LastUpdate': '2020-03-02T14:40:00.000Z',
   'Value': '521331.0',
   'FromUTC': '2020-06-17T12:00:00.000Z',
   'UntilUTC': '2020-06-17T13:00:00.000Z'}],
 [{'TimeserieId': '530',
   'ObjectID': 'EntryArnoldstein_TechnischeKapazitaetJaehrlich',
   'Unit': 'kWh/h',
   'Granularity': 'HOUR',
   'Name': 'TCY En Arnoldstein',
   'LastUpdate': '2020-03-02T19:00:08.000Z',
   'Value': '17377622',
   'FromUTC': '2020-06-17T11:00:00.000Z',
   'UntilUTC': '2020-06-17T12:00:00.000Z'},
  {'TimeserieId': '530',
   'ObjectID': 'EntryArnoldstein_TechnischeKapazitaetJaehrlich',
   'Unit': 'kWh/h',
   'Granularity': 'HOUR',
   'Name': 'TCY En Arnoldstein',
   'LastUpdate': '2020-03-02T19:00:08.000Z',
   'Value': '17377622',
   'FromUTC': '2020-06-17T12:00:00.000Z',
   'UntilUTC': '2020-06-17T13:00:00.000Z'}]]

#flatten the box list
#to eliminate the sublists
#and have only dictionaries within

flatten = chain.from_iterable
box = flatten(box)

#create dataframe
pd.DataFrame(box)
```

OR :

```
box = []
for entry in root.findall(".//Timeseries"):
    d = {ent.tag: ent.text for ent in entry.findall(".//*") if not ent.text.isspace()}    
    values = [ent.attrib for ent in entry.findall(".//Values/Value")]
    merger = product([d],values)
    merger = [{**dict1, **dict2} for dict1, dict2 in merger]
    box.append(merger)
```

Create dataframe - too wide to post results here :

```
#flatten box to remove sublists, and keep only the dictionaries : 
   flatten = chain.from_iterable
   pd.DataFrame(flatten(box))
```

Comment: Both solutions work perfectly, so I guess the crux is to designate the level at which the data begins? (i.e. .//Timeseries). thanks alot

Comment: Yea. Find the element that contains all the sub elements you are interested in, and adjust your code accordingly

Comment: If I want to pull all values in value ie. '<LastUpdate>2020-03-02T14:50:00.000Z</LastUpdate>
</Header>
<Values>
<Value FromUTC="2020-03-19T06:00:00.000Z" UntilUTC="2020-03-19T07:00:00.000Z">7696746.0</Value>
<Value FromUTC="2020-03-19T07:00:00.000Z" UntilUTC="2020-03-19T08:00:00.000Z">7696746.0</Value>
<Value FromUTC="2020-03-19T08:00:00.000Z" UntilUTC="2020-03-19T09:00:00.000Z">7696746.0</Value>
<Value FromUTC="2020-03-19T09:00:00.000Z" UntilUTC="2020-03-19T10:00:00.000Z">7696746.0</Value>
<Value FromUTC="2020-03-19T10:00:00.000Z" UntilUTC="2020-03-19T11:00:00.000Z">7696746.0</Value>'

Comment: Is this a new XML ? Part of the original question? A bit confused. Kindly explain a bit better

Comment: No, its the same XML just curious how to add the different values as rows, currently the code adds one row to the dataframe per iteration of the elements, ideally I would like to see the elements repeated for all the value line in that element group. So in the first example there would be 4 rows in box rather than 2 for the 2 value entries per element group. Is there a way to loop through values per group and append? These would be considered children or sub sub elements? thanks

Comment: still confused. kindly post an output of how the dataframe should look

Comment: Sure, in the first image of the question the desired dataframe shows 4 rows 2 values per the element group (there is a typo the first row should show 2020-06-17T12:00:00.000Z in the UntilUTC column) so the box variable would have 4 dicts in the list due to there being 2 values per element).

Comment: updated the image in the question to correct the typo to show desired dataframe output so you see the FromUTC and UntilUTC value changes warrant a new row.

Comment: much clearer now. I made some edits. Have a go at it; it should line up now

Comment: Ahh, thanks that works fine! I had to use a separate method to flatten the list, as when trying to produce the dataframe I got an error _data argument can't be an iterator_ so I used the below:               
 `box_list = []
  for sublist in box:
    for item in sublist:
        flat_list.append(item)
    
  box = pd.DataFrame(box_list)`   I was trying something along the same path but checking for content = [ent.attrib for ent in entry.findall(f".//Value")] which lead to a lot of frustration. Thanks for your help, will take a look at optimisation and really get a grasp on XML files.